# Установка сторонних библиотек для Python в Windows

Tags: python, windows

Привет.
Никак не могу найти статьи, описывающие установку сторонних библиотек python в windows.
Кто нибудь может помочь ссылкой или кратко описать порядок действий?

Answer (score 3):

Есть отличное место - [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/), его поддержкой занимается некий [Christoph Gohlke](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/). Там очень неплохой выбор сторонних библиотек, как правило, последних версий, под обе архитектуры Windows и под обе ветки python'а.

Это первое место, куда я иду в поисках нужной мне библиотеки.

Comment: pypi.python.org/pypi  
Официальный Python Package Index.

Comment: Это само собой, но если в библиотеке присутствует **C**-код, то на pypi далеко не всегда самое свежее. Для примера можете сравнить версии и варианты **lxml**.

Answer (score 1):

Я обычно вначале ищу exe/msi установщик под win. Если его нет то пробую установить пакет через утилиту easy_install из setuptools. Самый последний вариант - скачивание пакета, чтение инструкции по его установке и собственно установка. Это обычно команда типа такой: python setup.py install.

Comment: Прочитал что setuptools только для python 2.7 и раньше. Будет ли он работать с python 3.2 или для него нужны какие то другие утилиты?

Comment: с 3-й веткой python пока дела не имел, не подскажу.