# Python и информация о конфигурации ПК

Tags: python, железо

Интересует, как мне можно узнать определенную информацию о железе компьютера с помощью языка Python 3? 
Предположим, я хочу написать собственную оценку системы - мне нужно вытащить данные о процессоре, видеокарте и т.д. В каком направлении смотреть? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотреть нужно в сторону сторонних модулей. Возможно вам отчасти поможет [psutil](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/). Модули для windows и третьего питона в первую очередь берите [тут](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) (обоснование [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/76796/%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B8-python?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=86095#86095)).

Вряд ли в стандартную библиотеку когда-нибудь добавят подобный функционал, т.к. он нужен далеко не всем.

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю насколько верно, но я бы наверное воспользовался бы модулем os, но тогда не будет некоторой кроссплатформенности.

Comment: что конкретно пострадает из кроссплатформенности? я пишу только под win, в принципе.

Comment: ну не переносимость программы на другую ос, но так как под Вин я думаю проблем не будет.

Comment: а куда конкретно копать в os? полистал, что-то не смог нужное мне найти...

Comment: ну например можно передавать команды в cmd для получения той или иной инфы, можно воспользоватся еще модулем subprocess. А еще есть хорошая книга "Python в системном администрировании".

Answer (score 0):

"Python в системном администрировании" - книжечка  более подходящая к *NIX подобным ОС